# Rspec/Capybara: How to "expect to see Routing Error"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

How do I tell RSpec/Capybara to expect a RoutingError? The reason is I want users to click a link to "claim a plate" via PUT, not via GET/visiting the path.

Basically I want to `expect ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/plates/claim/1"`.

```
  scenario 'they have to click the claim link' do
    create_plates
    sign_in_as_doctor
    visit claim_plate_path(@plates.first.id)
    ?????
  end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
 scenario 'they have to click the claim link' do
    create_plates
    sign_in_as_doctor
    expect{visit claim_plate_path(@plates.first.id)}.to raise_error( ActionController::RoutingError)
  end
```

Comment: It's worth noting that when you're expecting to raise an error, you must pass expect a proc (with curly brackets) instead of simply calling it with parentheses.

Comment: using Minitest: `assert_raises(Exception) { visit claim_plate_path }`

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer didn't work for me. What I had to do is:

```
create_plates
sign_in_as_doctor
expect do
  visit claim_plate_path(@plates.first.id)
  expect(page).to have_content("make sure visit is completed")
end.to raise_error(ActionController::RoutingError)
```